# What is the best way to follow this book using XNA 4.0 instead of XNA 2.0

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, books

I found a reference to this book on the Microsofot Indie games forums: [http://www.amazon.com/dp/1430209798/ref=pe_385040_30332200_pe_309540_26725410_item](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430209798)

I'm really interested in it, because the example project is very close to the style of gameplay I'm looking for in my next game. The downside is, I was hoping to write the game in XNA 4.0 and maybe even Monogame.

Would the best option here be to just follow along with the book using xna 2.0, and then try to rewrite/update the app in xna 4 or monogame? Or, would it be better to start my project as an XNA 4.0 project, and then code along with the book, fixing any discrepancies as I come across them?

Comment: http://nelxon.com/resources/xna-3-1-to-xna-4-0-cheatsheet.php

Comment: 2 to 3 isn’t hard 3 to 4 is much more of a pita. The way rendering states are handled completely changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the features you're using from 2.0 and how they differ from those in 4.0. Likely the best option is to take it one step at a time. Start out with a 4.0 project, try using the book as is. When you come up against a problem, search specifically for that problem. Find out how to perform the required 2.0 exercise in a 4.0 way.

Since you ultimately want to use 4.0, I don't see a reason to learn 2.0 just because the book is written using that. It's likely what really interests you about the 2.0 book is the high level designs for the game made in the tutorials. In your goal of learning 4.0, finding out how to implement these high level 2.0 designs in 4.0 should be beneficial to you.

Comment: Thanks man, I think that is how I will proceed. Appreciate the input.

Comment: This link will be your friend.
http://nelxon.com/resources/xna-3-1-to-xna-4-0-cheatsheet.php

Comment: Ya, ClassicThunder posted that on the OP, it's a good resource.